# When returning from emacsclient to iterm2, terminal not getting focus

Tags: emacsclient

I'm using iterm2 v3.0.2 with fishs hell and tmux in osx. When I'm opening file via emacsclient and closing buffer - I'm successfully returning to terminal, BUT iterm2 window has no focus, so I have to click on window to gain it. I tested behaviour inside tmux session and outside - the same behaviour.

My command to run emacsclient:

```
emacsclient -c -a \"\" $argv
```

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with your window manager than with Emacs. Maybe you could try a different one?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to switch to your terminal app explicitly when <kbd>C-x #</kbd> (`server-edit`, the command to tell emacsclient that you finish editing):

```
(add-hook 'server-done-hook
          (defun open-terminal ()
            (shell-command "open -a Terminal")))
```

You also need to replace `Terminal` with `iTerm` since you are using iTerm2, not the built-in Terminal. I don't have iTerm2 installed on my Mac, so I can't try it myself.

Comment: nope, didn't helped(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and managed to get it working by adding

```
(defun switch-back-focus ()
  (shell-command "open -a iTerm"))

(add-hook 'server-done-hook 'switch-back-focus)
```

to my `init.el` file.

This does come with a couple of caveats - it will bring any Emacs frames to the front before it move back to iTerm2.

Thanks to @xuchunyang!